# Implement the *logger* function which will prepare data for logging

Tags: javascript, typescript, function

I have a task to
Implement the *logger* function which will prepare data for logging.It should have default service configuration `{serviceName: 'global', serviceId: 1}`
Some examples:

```
 // {"3-0":"[auth_service] Wrong email","3-1":"[auth_service] Wrong password","3-2":"[auth_service] Success login"}
  logger(['Wrong email', 'Wrong password', 'Success login'], {serviceName: 'auth_service', serviceId: 3});

  // {"1-0":"[global] Fatal error","1-1":"[global] Data corrupted"}
  logger(['Fatal error', 'Data corrupted']);
```

It should be written using Typescript.
I started to make this function but i dont know how to make it look like the example or like test samples..
This is what i did till now :

```
function logger(data: [], serviceInfo: {}) {
    //It should have default service configuration `{serviceName: 'global', serviceId: 1}`
    if (serviceInfo == undefined) {
        serviceInfo = {
            serviceName: "global",
            serviceId: 1,
        };
    } else {
     let obj = {
        
     }
     return obj;
    }
}
```

And unit tests:

```
describe('logger', () => {
    it('should log user events', () => {
        const result = logger(['User Event 1', 'User Event 2'], {serviceName: 'user', serviceId: 12});
        const expected = {
            '12-0': '[user] User Event 1',
            '12-1': '[user] User Event 2',
        };
        assert.deepStrictEqual(result, expected)
    });

    it('should log auth events', () => {
        const result = logger(['Event 1', 'Event 2', 'Event 3'], {serviceName: 'auth', serviceId: 2});
        assert.strictEqual(result['2-1'], '[auth] Event 2')
    });

    it('should log global events', () => {
        const result = logger(['Event 1', 'Event 2', 'Event 3']);
        assert.strictEqual(result['1-2'], '[global] Event 3')
    });
});
```

I thought about pushing the array into a different object,but i dont know how to make that depending on serviceId to appear like:

```
{
'12-0':'[user] User event 1'
}
```

where 12 is the service id, 0 is the array item index, [user] is the serviceName and the user event 1 is the array item.. I'm new in Javascript and Typescript and idk all the nuances.
Could you help me please? Thanks in advance!

Edit: I tried a little and came up with this function :

```
function logger(data: [], serviceInfo: {}) {
    //It should have default service configuration `{serviceName: 'global', serviceId: 1}`
  serviceInfo = {
      serviceName : 'Gigi',
      serviceId : 0
  }

    if (serviceInfo == undefined) {
        serviceInfo = {
            serviceName: "global",
            serviceId: 1,
        };
    } 
    let obj={}
    //obj[serviceInfo.serviceId.value + ]

    data.forEach(function (value, i) {
        //console.log('%d: %s', i, value);
        obj[serviceInfo.serviceId.value +'-'+ i] = '[' + serviceInfo.serviceName.value + ']' + value
    });
    console.log(obj)
}
```

But in console i get :

```
{
  'undefined-0': '[undefined]User Event 1',
  'undefined-1': '[undefined]User Event 2'
}
{
  'undefined-0': '[undefined]Event 1',
  'undefined-1': '[undefined]Event 2',
  'undefined-2': '[undefined]Event 3'
}
{
  'undefined-0': '[undefined]Event 1',
  'undefined-1': '[undefined]Event 2',
  'undefined-2': '[undefined]Event 3'
}
```

How to acces serviceName and serviceId if data is get from input not from function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the function,this way :

```
function logger(data: [], serviceInfo: {}) {
    if (serviceInfo == undefined) {
        serviceInfo = {
            serviceName: "global",
            serviceId: 1,
        };
    }
    let obj = {};

    data.forEach(function (value, i) {
        //console.log('%d: %s', i, value);
        obj[serviceInfo.serviceId + "-" + i] =
            "[" + serviceInfo.serviceName + "] " + value;
    });
    return obj
}
```

The problem upthere when i edited the question is that i incorectly accesed object property to get the value,so,now the function passes all test units.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing with typescript first, it is useful to write an interface.

```js
interface ServiceConfig {
    serviceName: string;
    serviceId: number;
  }
  function logger(messages: string[], config: ServiceConfig = { serviceName: 'global', serviceId: 1 }): Record<string, string> {
    const result: Record<string, string> = {};
  
    messages.forEach((message, index) => {
      const key = `${config.serviceId}-${index}`;
      const log = `[${config.serviceName}] ${message}`;
      result[key] = log;
    });
  
    return result;
  }
```